# Compile time error: can't find symbol Jlabel

Tags: java

I cant find the errors in my program. I'm just new into this any help will be most appreciated. I'm having errors that i dont know how to fix.  My full code is below:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class SampleApp3 extends JFrame{

Container pane;
JLabel label1;
JLabel label2;
Jlabel label3;
Jlabel label4;

 public SampleApp3(){
    pane=getContentPane();
    setSize(650, 540);
    setTitle("FormExample");
    pane.setLayout(null);

    label1= new JLabel("STI College Las Pinas",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label1.setToolTipText("Pogi Ako");
    label1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label1.setBounds(100,210,325,50);
    pane.add(label1,"Center");

    label2= new JLabel("Charles Jason Decena",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label2.setToolTipText("Si Charles ay Pogi");
    label2.setForeground(Color.blue);
    pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label2.setBounds(110,215,320,48);
    pane.add(label2,"Center");

    label3= new JLabel("BSIT-124",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label3.setToolTipText("Ehem si Decena ay pogi");
    label3.setForeground(Color.blue);
    pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label3.setBounds(120,220,315,46);
    pane.add(label3,"Center");

    label4= new JLabel("Computer Programming 2",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label4.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label4.setToolTipText("Well Pogi talaga ako");
    label4.setForeground(Color.blue);
    pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label4.setBounds(130,225,315,44);
    pane.add(label4,"Center");

    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SampleApp3= new SampleApp3(); //and this one 
app.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The error message says that `Jlabel` 3 and 4 "cant find symbol" and also contains the text sampleapp3.  Can anyone help me with what is causing the error?

Comment: It's `JLabel`, not `Jlabel`

Comment: Wonder if that belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: IMO I wouldnt downvote that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This came to me to review as your first post. Please (re)read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In your case, producing a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might have helped you find the problem (a typo in `Jlabel label3;
Jlabel label4;` - the `Jlabel` should be `JLabel`) before you posted the question and in any case would have shortened the code you had to post.

Comment: @JensG Only working (error free) code is on topic on cr

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew why I didn't flag it. ;-)

Comment: Sorry im just new into this world , but still there is a problem it says cant find symbol ? on this line SampleApp3= new SampleApp3();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive

```
Jlabel label3;
Jlabel label4;
```

Are both invalid.  The class is `JLabel` (notice the L is capitalized)

Comment: --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
C:\Users\mike\Documents\SampleApp3.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
  
SampleApp3= new SampleApp3();
  ^
  symbol:   variable SampleApp3
  location: class SampleApp3
C:\Users\mike\Documents\SampleApp3.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
 app.setVisible(true);
 ^
  symbol:   variable app
  location: class SampleApp3
2 errors

Comment: @CharlieDecena You need to read a tutorial on Java/OOP fundamentals. This is really basic stuff. You need a variable name. Like so:  `SampleApp3 someName = new SampleApp3();`

Comment: @CharlieDecena Your comment's error has nothing to do with the original question, but it shows that you are not familiar with the fundamentals of OOP and Java.  Here at SO we're happy to help, but we won't debug your program for you.  You really should look into a tutorial and learn how to program in Java and then use SO for asking questions that you didn't understand and we can clarify for you.  If my answer answered your original post, please click on the check mark to accept it!  Good luck!